# Configuring SASL support in libmemcached

Tags: memcached, sasl

I'm trying to build `libmemcached` with SASL support on OS X Mountain Lion.

I have built `memcached` (1.4.15) with SASL support:

```
    $ memcached -S -vv
    Initialized SASL.
    slab class   1: chunk size        96 perslab   10922
    ...
    slab class  42: chunk size   1048576 perslab       1
    <17 server listening (binary)
    <18 server listening (binary)
    <19 send buffer was 9216, now 3728270
    <20 send buffer was 9216, now 3728270
    <19 server listening (udp)
    <20 server listening (udp)
    ...
```

I am trying to build `libmemcached` with SASL support too. I have tried the following:

```
    $ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local \
      --with-memcached-sasl=/usr/local/bin/memcached
    ...
    $ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local \
      --with-memcached-sasl="/usr/local/bin/memcached -S"
    ...
```

But the resulting configuration summary is the same for both:

```
Configuration summary for libmemcached version 1.0.11
       * Installation prefix:       /usr/local
       * System type:               apple-darwin12.2.0
       * Host CPU:                  x86_64
       * C Compiler:                i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
       * C Flags:                    -O2 -Werror -Wall -Wextra -std=c99 -Wbad-function-cast -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Woverride-init
       * C++ Compiler:              i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
       * C++ Flags:                  -O2 -Werror -Wall -Wextra -Wpragmas -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Waddress -Wchar-subscripts -Wcomment -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wfloat-equal -Wformat=2 -Wmissing-field-initializers -Wmissing-noreturn -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wnormalized=id -Woverloaded-virtual -Wpointer-arith -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wsign-compare -Wstrict-overflow=1 -Wswitch-enum -Wundef -Wunused-variable -Wwrite-strings -fwrapv -ggdb
       * CPP Flags:                 -I/usr/local/include
       * Assertions enabled:        no
       * Debug enabled:             no
       * Warnings as failure:       no
       * SASL support:
```

Am I doing something incorrectly? Thanks.

Comment: It works when I set `ac_enable_sasl=1`. Is this a variable that is supposed to be set by `autoconf`? It seems like a cheat to me.

Comment: My mistake, `pylibmc` still raises `TypeError: libmemcached does not support SASL`.

Comment: These comments should probably be added to your post, FYI.

Comment: Why? My second comment was to clarify that my first comment was incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

OK so here is a way, it's obviously not the 'correct' way but SASL support in libmemcached seems somewhat bitrotted.

1. Download libmemcached-1.0.8 (1.0.9 and later require code modifications sadly as SASL support hasn't been kept up-to-date with changes in the code).
2. Untar, change to folder.
3. sed -i -e s/ax_cv_sasl/ac_enable_sasl/ m4/ax_sasl.m4
4. sed -i -e "s/-pthread -pthreads/-lpthread -lpthreads/" m4/ax_pthread.m4
5. ./configure
6. make
7. sudo make install

This should get it up and running on OSX (you need to do the same on Linux, or at least I did with Ubuntu).

Comment: Hi David, I tried this and the results of the configure (http://codepad.org/SN414faT) still do not indicate SASL support. Is that true or just a reporting bug?

Comment: I've followed the steps and it does appear that SASL support was compiled (http://codepad.org/MSIV76ir) but after following these steps (http://trondn.blogspot.fr/2010/02/memcached-with-sasl-on-opensolaris.html) it appears that the build was unsuccessful (http://codepad.org/haQ6AB6Z).

Comment: Hey John, one thing I had wrong was I recommended libmemcached 1.0.9. I should have said 1.0.8. The later version requires a small change to the code, it's an easy one but I'd say just use 1.0.8 as the above instructions work fine for it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible on OS X Mountain Lion (and possibly other versions of OS X). I'm going to raise the issue with the `libmemcached` team.

Comment: Issue URL: https://bugs.launchpad.net/libmemcached/+bug/1056093